# vuex filter object in store

Tags: javascript, object, filter, vuex

I have an object of objects in my Vuex state that I am trying to filter to update the UI. I am having trouble filtering the object by one of the properties in the object. I am trying to avoid creating a temporary object to hold the filtered data.

Here is my data object:

```
var data = {
    'xxxxx' : {
        id: 'xxxxx',
        assessed_value: 1900,
        creditid: 'zzzzz',
        full_value: 100,
        population: 200
    },
    'yyyy' : {
        id: 'yyyy',
        assessed_value: 2000,
        creditid: 'pppp',
        full_value: 300,
        population: 400
    },
    'aaaa' : {
        id: 'aaaa',
        assessed_value: 5000,
        creditid: 'pppp',
        full_value: 100,
        population: 600
    }
};
```

I am trying to filter by creditid. For example, I want to retrieve all objects in the state with a creditid === 'pppp'.

I created a function that filters by creditid but it returns an array of objects.

```
function getCreditId(obj, key, val) {
   return Object.values(obj).filter(x => x[key] === val);
}
```

I would like to filter the state by data[creditid] so that I am not creating another object. But not sure how to bypass the keys for each object ['yyyy', 'aaaa'] when doing the filter. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it is by using the `reduce` function.

```
var attribute = 'creditid';
var value = 'pppp';
var keys = Object.keys(data);
var result = keys.reduce(function(a, k) {
  if (data[k][attribute] === value) {
    a.push(data[k]);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
```